# why does SWIG make illegal wrapper from in and argout typemaps?

Tags: swig

I am trying to write an `argout` SWIG typemap.

From this interface `foobar.i` file, which seems perfectly legal to me:

```
%{
void f(int arg[2]) {}
%}

%typemap(in, numinputs = 0) int [ANY] {}

%typemap(argout) int arg[ANY] {
  PySequence_SetItem($input, 0, PyInt_FromLong(0));
}

void f(int arg[2]) {}
```

SWIG compiles an illegal `foobar_wrap.cxx` file, because it contains the following fragment:

```
PySequence_SetItem(, 0, PyInt_FromLong(0));
```

replacing `$input` with nothing.  If I omit the `in` typemap, then the wrapper is correct.

Why?

I just want to ignore the input, and fill up the array on the output. The SWIG manual clearly says to use `numinputs=0`.

Comment: `numinputs=0` doesn't just ignore the input, it makes sure there isn't any at all so there's nothing to substitute for `$input` in the argout. What you want by the sound of things is like my earlier examples without `numinputs=0` but with the for loop removed from the "in" typemap.

Comment: I'll write a full answer later when I've got more time if nobody else beats me to it.

Comment: It's OK I figured it out.  I guess my beef here is with the manual.  The manual is completely unclear and misleading, about how to output results, not as printout, but as filled in "outpput" arguments.  For example, the manual clearly states that $input is available for argout typemap.  Wrong, it is not available, if there is also a matching (in, numinputs=0) typemap.

Comment: Malek Can you please post an answer for benefit of everyone?

Comment: The manual is pretty good all things considered, but I'm sure they'd like a patch if you felt like clarifying this one. (It does make sense though when you understand what's going on under the hood with numinputs=0 - there's simply nothing to substitute) We'd also like it if you wrote your solution up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. I guess my beef here is with the manual. The manual does not say, how to output results, not as printout, but as filled in "output" arguments. For example, the manual clearly states that $input is available for argout typemap. Wrong, it is not available, if there is also a matching (in, numinputs) typemap.