# pass simple java array to primitive c-array swig

Tags: java, android, c++, arrays, swig

i want to pass a simple java array to c.

At the moment i do it with the following .i File.

```
%module example

%include "arrays_java.i"
%include "example.h"
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
```

with the arrays_java.i header java arrays was accepted. 
But it make a full copy of the array and this is to slow for me.
I tried to build a typemap with these I can use the GetDoubleArray function, to get the pointer of the java array.
Before I use swig i build my own wrapper with JNI GetDoubleArrayElements and this was much faster.

Below you can see my try to use Jni functions in a typemap.

```
%typemap(jtype) (double *values, int lenght) "double[]"
%typemap(jstype) (double *values, int lenght) "double[]"
%typemap(javain) (double *values, int lenght) "$javainput"
%typemap(jni) (double *values, int lenght) "jdoubleArray"
%typemap(in) (double *values, int lenght) {

    $1 = (double *)JCALL2(GetDoubleArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
    $2 = (int)    JCALL1(GetArrayLength,       jenv, $input);
 }

 %apply (double * DOUBLE, int LENGTH)   { (double * doubleArray, long len) };
```

But swig builds me only a javaclass (SWIGTYPE_p_double) which i should use. 
I only want to pass a simple java array and use this java array pointer in c.

hope you can help me thx

EDIT:

Here you can see my complete .i File. I correct the lenght fail. same problem

```
%module exampleModule
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "arrays_java.i"
#include <string>
#include <vector>





%template(nativeDoubleVector) std::vector<double>;



%typemap(jtype) (double *values, int length) "double[]"
%typemap(jstype) (double *values, int length) "double[]"
%typemap(javain) (double *values, int length) "$javainput"
%typemap(jni) (double *values, int length) "jdoubleArray"
%typemap(in) (double *values, int length) {

   $1 = (double *)JCALL2(GetDoubleArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
   $2 = (int)    JCALL1(GetArrayLength,       jenv, $input);
}

%apply (double * values, int length)   { (double * doubleArray, long len) };




/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "example.h"
%{
  #include "example"
%}
```

and the .h File

```
class example
{
public:
    example(int width, int height);
    ~example();
    test(double *values, int length);
 };
```

Were i can see the -Wall output ? i try it, but i become no output in android studio terminal

Comment: Looks like a typo  in your spelling of the word "length" but there are more issues too. Run SWIG with -Wall argument and note the warnings I'm pretty sure you'll see on `%apply`. Could you show us example.h and your .i file with your typemaps included though?

Comment: i edited my post. thx for answer

Answer (score 0):

i get a first half Solution.

```
//java float[] in c float arr
%typemap(jstype) double[] "double[]"
%typemap(jtype) double[] "double[]"
%typemap(jni) double[] "jdoubleArray"
%typemap(javain) double[] "$javainput"
%typemap(in) double[] {
    $1 = JCALL2(GetDoubleArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
}
```

This code allows me to use the java array without a copy of it. 
But i can´t change values at c side  and java side know about it.
Java side has the old values.

I know the fault. At wrap.cpp the function ReleasDoubleArrayElements is missing.
When i insert it at the wrap.cpp all is good. Below you can see the wrap.cpp which generated from swig.

```
SWIGEXPORT void JNICALL      Java_com_example_glm_ndk_1swig_1example_exampleJNI_Circle_1testfunktion(JNIEnv   *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jfloatArray jarg2, jint jarg3) {
   Circle *arg1 = (Circle *) 0 ;
   float *arg2 ;
   int arg3 ;

   (void)jenv;
   (void)jcls;
   (void)jarg1_;
   arg1 = *(Circle **)&jarg1; 
   {
     arg2 = jenv->GetFloatArrayElements(jarg2, NULL);
   }
   arg3 = (int)jarg3; 
   (arg1)->testfunktion(arg2,arg3);
   jenv->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(jarg2, arg2, NULL);//insert manually
```

}

But what must I tell swig to insert this function ?

edit:

I got the solution. Thank you Flexo. You helped me with an another thread. [python arg out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373259/swig-in-typemap-works-but-argout-do)
I must use %typemap(argout). below you can see my solution which workes for me.

```
%typemap(jstype) double[] "double[]"
%typemap(jtype) double[] "double[]"
%typemap(jni) double[] "jdoubleArray"
%typemap(javain) double[] "$javainput"
%typemap(in) double[] {
     $1 = JCALL2(GetDoubleArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
}
%typemap(argout) double[]{
    JCALL3(ReleaseDoubleArrayElements,jenv, $input, $1, 0);
}
```

It´s much faster than copy the array to c.