# Returning arguments in SWIG/Python

Tags: python, swig, typemaps

According to Swig docs and the marvelous explanation at [SWIG in typemap works, but argout does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373259/swig-in-typemap-works-but-argout-does-not) by @Flexo, the `argout` typemap turns reference arguments into return values in Python.

I have a scenario, in which I pass a `dict`, which then is converted to an `unordered_map` in `typemap(in)`, which then gets populated in the C++ lib. Stepping through the code, I can see the mapping changed after it returned from C++, so I wonder why there is not a possibility to just convert the `unordered_map` back in place in to the `dict` that was passed. Or is it possible by now and I'm just overlooking something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a little confused as to what exactly you are asking, but my understanding is:

- You have an "in" typemap to convert a Python `dict` to a C++ `unordered_map` for some function argument.
- The function then modifies the `unordered_map`.
- After completion of the function, you want the Python `dict` updated to the current `unordered_map`, and are somehow having trouble with this step.
- Since you know how to convert a `dict` to an `unordered_map`, I assume you basically do know how to convert the `unordered_map` back to the `dict` using the Python C-API, but are somehow unsure into which SWIG typemap to put the code.

So, under these assumptions, I'll try to help:

- "the argout typemap turns reference arguments into return values in Python". Not really, although it is mostly used for this purpose. An ["argout" typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn32) simply supplies code to deal with some function argument (internally referred to as `$1`) that is inserted into the wrapper code *after* the C++ function is called. Compare this with an "in" typemap that supplies code to convert the supplied Python argument `$input` to a C++ argument `$1`, which is obviously inserted into the wrapper code *before* the C++ function is called.
- The original passed Python `dict` can be referred to in the "argout" typemap as `$input`, and the modified `unordered_map` as `$1` (see the SWIG docs linked above).
- Therefore, all you need to do is write an "argout" typemap for the same argument signature as the "in" typemap that you already have, and insert the code (using the Python C-API) to update the contents of the Python `dict` (`$input`) to reflect the contents of the `unordered_map` (`$1`).
- Note that this is different from the classical use of "argout" typemaps, which would typically convert the `$1` back to a new Python `dict` and append this to the Python return object, which you can refer to by `$result`.

I hope this helps. If you are still stuck at some point, please edit your question to make clear at which point you are having trouble.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, m7thon! The second last bullet was the piece I was missing. From the provided Swig examples, I thought that your last bullet was the only possible way of passing back the data (by using return values).

Comment: @wr m7thon is spot on with this answer. The one thing you have to watch out for and make your own mind up on is what a Python developer (i.e. the user of your bindings) expect the behaviour to be. Ideally you want to take the least confusing route. For me, normally in Python that's to make input arguments immutable, because unlike C++ you can't infer easily (e.g.) via const/not reference what the behavior will be. That pretty much only leaves returning a value instead as an option, which often makes sense because return val isn't being used to indicate success/fail in well designed interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I am well aware of that the user has already solved his issue, but here goes a solution. Some validation of inputs may be introduced to avoid non-string values of the input dictionary.

Header file

```
// File: test.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

void method(std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>* inout) {

  for( const auto& n : (*inout) ) {
    std::cout << "Key:[" << n.first << "] Value:[" << n.second << "]\n";
  }

  (*inout)["BLACK"] = "#000000";
};
```

Interface file

```
// File : dictmap.i
%module dictmap

%{
  #include "test.h"
%}

%include "typemaps.i"

%typemap(in) std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>* (std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> temp) {

  PyObject *key, *value;
  Py_ssize_t pos = 0;

  $1 = &temp;

  temp = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
  while (PyDict_Next($input, &pos, &key, &value)) {
    (*$1)[PyString_AsString(key)] = std::string(PyString_AsString(value));
  }
}

%typemap(argout) std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>* {
 $result = PyDict_New();
 for( const auto& n : *$1) {
   PyDict_SetItemString($result, n.first.c_str(),
            PyString_FromString(n.second.c_str()));
 }
}
%include "test.h"
```

Test

```
import dictmap
out = dictmap.method({'WHITE' : '#FFFFFF'})
```

Output is an updated dictionary

```
In[2]: out
Out[3] : {'BLACK': '#000000', 'WHITE': '#FFFFFF'}
```

Comment: Note that when working with python3, you may find that `PyString_AsString` keeps returning a null pointer. You may need to use `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` in place of `PyString_AsString`.